# Using "when" in Kotlin matches with different value

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on Android Studio with Kotlin.

My app has 3 buttons (let's say button A, B, C) on an Activity and it works fine.

However, when I debug the app, the evaluated value by "when" keyword matches with different value.

This is the code.

```
fun setOnClickListener(button: Button) {
    button.setOnClickListener {
        val fragment =
            when(button.id) {
                R.id.aButton -> AFragment()
                R.id.bButton -> BFragment()
                R.id.cButton -> CFragment()
                else -> throw Exception()
            }
    }
```

When I click the button B, `button.id` matches with `R.id.bButton`.

That is what I intended to do but I got confused when I see the value of `button.Id` and `R.id.bButton` because the `button.Id` is 2131165292 and `R.id.bButton` is -1000025.

Would you describe why these 2 different values are evaluated the same?

**[Additional Information]**

I check the value with just putting the cursor on `button.Id` and `R.id.bButton` like below.

[image]

[image]

```
 public boolean performClick() {
        final boolean result;
        final ListenerInfo li = mListenerInfo;
        if (li != null && li.mOnClickListener != null) {
            playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
            li.mOnClickListener.onClick(this);
            result = true;
        } else {
            result = false;
        }

        sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED);
        return result;
    }
```

And this is the sack trace which the debugger is stopped on `when(button.id)`.

```
onClick:22, SubActivity$setOnClickListener$1 (Package name of my app)

performClick:5637, View (android.view)

run:22429, View$PerformClick (android.view)

handleCallback:751, Handler (android.os)

dispatchMessage:95, Handler (android.os)

loop:154, Looper (android.os)

main:6119, ActivityThread (android.app)

main:776, ZygoteInit (com.android.internal.os)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added [Additional Information] on the post.The way I checked the values is just putting the cursor on them although I am not pretty sure it is the right way to see values with Android Studito...

Comment: From where you call this function and what you pass into it? Please add that code here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added the stack trace to the post. So it is called from performClick method of View.java and it calls a method which create Fragment.

Comment: Where you got `-1000025` from? While it's pretty clear you confuse signed with unsigned, these two do not match when normalized

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added an image of where I got `-1000025`. The image is after stepping over by F8 from `when(button.id) { `

Comment: When you click on that R.id.bButton it should open generated source for resource file ids. What value you got there for that id?

Comment: Nothing open up by left click. Context menu open by right click but I can't find any generated source there. Do I need any settings to open generated source by clicking `R.id.bButton`? Is generated source for resource filed ids like `android:id="@+id/bButton"`?